# How to integrate paypal sandbox classic api in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, api, paypal

I am trying to integrate paypal test environment for testing purpose. But when click on but it redirects on sandbox home page as bellow

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/home

While I am using www.paypal.com it redirect to correct payment form. Following is my code.

```
decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(itemCost);
    string returnURL = "";
   // returnURL += "https://www.paypal.com/xclick/business=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(email);
    returnURL += "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?business =" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(email);
    //Passing Item Name as dynamic
    returnURL += "&item_name=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(itemName);
    returnURL += "&item_number=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(itemNumber);
    returnURL += "&amount=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(price.ToString());
    returnURL += "&currency=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(currency);
    returnURL += "&return=http://localhost:38436/";
    returnURL += "&cancel_return=http://localhost:38436/";
    returnURL += "&data-env=sandbox";
    return returnURL;
```

Please let me how to use sandbox so that it can redirect on payment page working correct in live environment.

I create 1 business account and one individual account in www.developer.paypal.com

Please advise me
Many Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: I was missing to pass command as  https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing to pass cmd=_xclick in query string.
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick
now working fine  :)